# Changing Url method in YII2

Tags: yii2

My url is in yii2:

$component_id = '175';
$used = '1';

```
Yii::$app->UrlManager->createUrl('component/datafield&c_id='.$component_id.'&value='.$used);
```

Its runs  :

```
index.php?r=component%2Fdatafield%26c_id%3D176%26value%3D1
```

it shows page not found :-((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example from the Yii2 guide (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#routing-and-url-creation):

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

// Url::to() calls UrlManager::createUrl() to create a URL
$url = Url::to(['post/view', 'id' => 100]);
```

Assuming you have "ComponentController" with action "actionDataField":

```
$url = Url::to(['component/datafield','c_id'=>$component_id,'value'=>$used]);
```